# Is FreeBSD (64 Bit) supported in Google Cloud VMware Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I am migrating VMware workloads having OS as Is FreeBSD (64 Bit) to Google Cloud VMware Engine. Does GCVE supports the OS FreeBSD (64 Bit)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, FreeBSD is supported. Versions from 11.3 to 14.0 are available.

You can see the list of available images using the CLI:

```
gcloud compute images list \
  --project freebsd-org-cloud-dev \
  --no-standard-images
```

I have personally set up multiple FreeBSD systems in Google Cloud for large storage systems with ZFS. FreeBSD works very well in Google Cloud.

Note: When you create a VM, make sure the boot disk is at least 32 GB.

Example CLI command (Windows syntax):

```
@set GCP_NAME=freebsd
@set GCP_PROJECT_ID=my-project
@set GCP_ZONE=us-west1-a
@set GCP_MACHINE_TYPE=e2-medium
@set GCP_SSH_KEYPAIR=gcp_ssh_keypair.txt
@set GCP_DISK_SIZE=500
@set GCP_DISK_TYPE=pd-ssd

gcloud beta compute instances create %GCP_NAME% ^
--project=%GCP_PROJECT_ID% ^
--zone=%GCP_ZONE% ^
--machine-type=%GCP_MACHINE_TYPE% ^
--image=freebsd-12-2-release-amd64 ^
--image-project=freebsd-org-cloud-dev ^
--tags http-server ^
--scopes cloud-platform ^
--metadata-from-file=ssh-keys=%GCP_SSH_KEYPAIR%
```

I create my own SSH keypairs and then specify the key when creating an instance. You can delete the option **--metadata-from-file** if you do not do the same. The rest the options are fairly standard for any OS that you might select.